# Not working checkboxes and how to remove sorting symbol for particular column in datatable

Tags: jquery

Below is my coding, if i checked  checkbox all the  check boxes are checked and displaying count of records at the first time. in the second time if i checked  checkbox am getting count of records but checkboxes are checked
and sort icon in  column

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive : true,              
        }); 
        
        $("#selectall").click(function() {
            $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);               
            if ($('.case').attr('checked', this.checked)) {
                count = this.checked ? $(".case").length : 0;
                username_Must.innerHTML = count;
            }
            
            
        });         
        $(".case").click(function() {
            count = $(".case:checked").length;
            if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
                $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
            }
            username_Must.innerHTML = count;
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th> 
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>ReferenceId</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="adminSms">
            <tr>
             <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" /></td> 
                <td><s:property value="studentname" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="phone" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="ref" /></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem description:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code for the datatable.

```
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
                        responsive : true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
                {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": 'no-sort'},
            ]              
                    });
```

Add 'no-sort' class for the column which you want to disable for sort.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                                                id="dataTables-example">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr> <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th> 
                                                        <th class='no-sort'>Student Name</th>
                                                        <th>Phone</th>
                                                        <th>ReferenceId</th>

                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <s:iterator value="adminSms">
                                                        <tr>
                                                         <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" /></td> 
                                                            <td><s:property value="studentname" /></td>
                                                            <td><s:property value="phone" /></td>
                                                            <td><s:property value="ref" /></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </s:iterator>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

For Checkbox count:

```
$("#selectall").click(function() {
                    $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);               
                    if ($('.case').prop('checked', this.checked)) {
                        count = this.checked ? $(".case").length : 0;
                        username_Must.innerHTML = count;
                    }


                });         
                $(".case").click(function() {
                    count = $(".case:checked").length;
                    if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
                        $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);
                    } else {
                        $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
                    }
                    username_Must.innerHTML = count;
                });
```

Comment: "aoColumnDefs": [ 
                {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": 'no-sort'},
            ]  what to put aoColumnDefs give me an example

Comment: I have tried this "aoColumnDefs": [{"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0]}], for the first column its not working...  if i give like "aoColumnDefs": [{"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [1]}], the second column is working

Comment: How to send checked data usnig ajax

Comment: why if i use id instead of class for the second checkbox count is not properly working

Comment: if i do <th> <a hfer="" id="selectall">ALL</a></th>

Comment: ya its working if i replace checkbox with anchor its not working

Comment: `$("#selectall").click(function() {
                    $('.case').prop('checked', true);               
                    if ($('.case').prop('checked', true)) {
                        count = this.checked ? $(".case").length : 0;
                        username_Must.innerHTML = count;
                    }


                });  ` Try this one

Comment: count coming zero if i select all

Comment: when i click link all the checkboxes are checked but count is zero and if click again it does not uncheck all checkboxes

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nhw3aL4a/5/  check this jsfiddle , it is working now , If it is helpful to you , then don't forgot to appreciate my work